# Как сделать вывод инфы из БД на подобие вот этой?

Tags: android, adapter

[image]

Т.е. чтобы выводила полоску с буквой "Г",а потом контакты все,которые на Г начинаются, потом все контакты на "Д" и т.д., не знаю, как это реализовать с помощью **simplecursoradapter**, т.к. он берёт данные из БД по очереди и пихать в одну колонку букву,а потом контакты, это "убого", прошу вас помочь, или я что-то не знаю про **simplecursoradapter**

Comment: Свой адаптер пишите.

Comment: >Евгений, Танин Папа

Наверно крутой чел :)

Comment: Отец моей девушки))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sectioning Your ListView](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/07/05/listview-tips-tricks-2-section-your-listview/)

[Android ListView with an alphabet scroller](http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/android-listview-alphabet-scroller)

Answer (score 3):

Сделайте [свой адаптер](http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2013/02/10/Implementing-a-ListView-with-AlphabetIndexer-and-CursorAdapter-on-Android) с блекджеком и [`AlphabetIndexer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AlphabetIndexer.html)'ом.